# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined Angular 14 with NGRX

Tags: angular, ngrx

I receive the above error in my Effect, and I cant see why.

Here is my effect:

```
login$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(fromAuthActions.login),
        switchMap((auth) => {
          return this.authService.doLogin(auth.email, auth.password)
            .pipe(map((data) => fromAuthActions.loginComplete({ profile: <LoggedInUser>data, isLoggedIn: true })))
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );
```

here are my two actions:

```
export const login = createAction('[Auth] login', props<{ email: string, password: string }>());

export const loginComplete = createAction(
  '[Auth] loginComplete',
  props<{ profile: LoggedInUser; isLoggedIn: boolean }>()
);
```

My reducer, where profile is declared `LoggedInUser | null`

```
on(authActions.loginComplete, (state, { profile, isLoggedIn }) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      profile,
      isLoggedIn,
    };
  }),
```

and my Service that makes the call to the server (I get to the server and I can see via the Network tab in the browser, that the server is returning the correct data).

```
doLogin(email: string, password: string): any {
    let user: LoginUser = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    var returnval = this.crud.post<LoggedInUser>(user, 'Auth/login');
      returnval.subscribe((e: LoggedInUser) => { return e; });

  }
```

I think my issue is that on my doLogin method my return type is `any` and so in my effect `data` passed back is of type `any` but I'm strongly typing data to `LoggedInUser` as that is what I really want. Also, i'm not sure about the Subscribe in my doLogin method, but if I dont have it there, then the server does not get called.

I am struggling to get this right. any help Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `doLogin` implementation:

```
  doLogin(email: string, password: string): any {
    let user: LoginUser = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    var returnval = this.crud.post<LoggedInUser>(user, 'Auth/login');
      returnval.subscribe((e: LoggedInUser) => { return e; });

  }
```

Here, `returnval` does nothing, and `doLogin` does not return anything - hence your error message: a function that returns nothing will implicitly return `undefined`.

I believe you intended to actually return the observable that `crud.post` creates.

```
  doLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    let user: LoginUser = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    return this.crud.post<LoggedInUser>(user, 'Auth/login');
  }
```

Like this, `doLogin` will return the actual `Observable`, which in turn can be `pipe`d within your effect.

Tip: never type your functions to return `any`. This will allow typescript to detect when you made such a mistake early on.

---

### Extra info

> Also, i'm not sure about the Subscribe in my doLogin method, but if I dont have it there, then the server does not get called.

`.subscribe` starts the observable immediately, that's why your server isn't called if you never subscribe to it. Observables do not execute unless something subscribes to them; however for ngrx effects you don't want to subscribe to anything immediately.

Your `login$` observable is actually a composed observable that listens to all actions, but it filters out to only emit something if the `login` action was emitted. This is done by the line `ofType(fromAuthActions.login),`.

When you emit an action of type `fromAuthActions.login`(by calling `store.dispatch(login(...))` somewhere), the `login$` observable will then **switch** to another observable - the one returned by `this.authService.doLogin`. This is what the `switchMap` operator is for, and this is why you need to return an observable from `doLogin`: you want to have `login$` switching into the new observable in order to kick off your POST request.

The Observable returned by `doLogin` will then be `pipe`d again, this time returning another action - which is what ngrx effects expect. NGRX will know to interpret the new action("login complete") in another effect.

Comment: I have changed my `doLogin` as per your example.  The error has now gone, however the data doesn't seem to get in to the Logincomplete action which is the bit that puts the data into state. If I add ...`console.log(data.token); fromAuthActions.loginComplete....` the data shows in the console.

Comment: Remove { dispatch: false } in your effect. This option is only used, when you don't want to dispatch a response action, e.g. when you just want to trigger a router navigation event or something else.

Comment: @hmartini thanks, I realised that after I posted my comment. The Answer given solved my initial issue though, so I gave Badashi the credit. I set dispaitch to true and added a return to the loginComplete action.